# Can't create drawable file when the root label is <set>

Tags: android, set, drawable

As you can see, there is no auto-complete option for `set` label:

[image]

Comment: i think <set> tag not availabel for drawables... <shape>, <layer-list> tags are commonly used for drawables..

Comment: see `guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root tag `<set>` is not allowd for drawable files. It is only available for anim files i.e. only files kept in anim folder can have `<set>` as root tag.

For drawable files we can have tags like `<shape>, <layer-list>, <selector>` etc. 
refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) link for more information about drawable resources.